# Scraping video url from multiple pages of a website

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am doing scraping using selenium. i want to scrape all the video urls that are present in the 626 products on the 25 pages. but while extracting the url it gives me the href link of the thumbnail of image file source.

```
import selenium
import pandas as pd 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, ElementNotVisibleException,StaleElementReferenceException

#First we will connect to webdriver
driver=webdriver.Chrome(r'/Users/ankit/chromedriver')
#Open the webpage with webdriver
driver.get('https://www.getapp.com/hr-employee-management-software/human-resources/')

URL2 = []  # for product pages
URL = []  # for storing all the pages
for i in range(1, 27):
    URL.append(f"https://www.getapp.com/hr-employee-management-software/human-resources/page-{i}/")

# visiting all the pages and scraping the products/Read More About... Links
for p in URL:
    driver.get(p)
    for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
        '//a[@data-testid="listing-item_text-link_read-more-about-product"]'
    ):
        URL2.append(i.get_attribute("href"))

# extracting and storing the video url of the product
video_url=[]

for i in URL2:
    driver.get(i)
    try:
        i=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/section[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/img")
        video_url.append(i.get_attribute("src"))
    except NoSuchElementException:
        video_url.append('--')
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the image `src` attribute having the embed video name, using that unique name you can form the video url.

eg. `src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YtktfxBFgJU/hqdefault.jpg"`

Here the unique code `YtktfxBFgJU` can be added in suffix of a default url like below: `https://www.youtube.com/embed/YtktfxBFgJU` you will get video url.

Check this method may be helpful

Comment: Not able to move to another url

Comment: Cause i want to scrape all the urls of 626 products in which videos are present

Comment: And doing it manually i don't think it will help